# Stack alignment macos 64bit assembly(nasm)

Tags: assembly, x86-64, nasm, calling-convention, abi

I am creating my strdup function using assembly code (intel x64 nasm)
And I am testing my code, it perfectly works on Mac OS, but i wonder why -_-;;
Because, as i know, i should do 16 bit stack alignment in Mac OS.

the function i gonna do is

```
char *my_strdup(const char *s)
{
    char *ret;

    ret = malloc(my_strlen(s) + 1);
    if (!ret)
        return (0);
    my_strcpy(ret, s);
    return (ret);
}
```

And here is the asm code

```
        section .text
        global  _my_strdup
        extern  _my_strlen
        extern  _malloc
        extern  _my_strcpy

_my_strdup:
        call _my_strlen         ; <---- Question1
        mov rcx, rax            ; rcx = length
        inc rcx                 
        push rdi                ; 16-byte alignment / save s address into stack
        mov rdi, rcx            ; param = length + 1
        call _malloc            ; <---- Question2
        cmp rax, 0
        je  done                ; if ret = 0, goto done
        pop rsi                 ; rsi = src
        mov rdi, rax            ; rdi = dest
        call _my_strcpy         ; <----- Question1
        jmp done
done:
        ret
```

Question1 - How my code is possible to call _my_strlen / _my_strcpy ?
I didn't push anything into stack before call _my_strlen. That means, _my_strlen "call instruction" will push 8 bytes of return address into stack so that it must to generate 16-bytes not alignment error. But actually, it works very well.

By the same reason like _my_strlen, _my_strcpy should have problem of 16-bytes alignment error... I don't understand why it works.

Question2 - I want to make sure that the reason why calling malloc works. 
I think, my code malloc part works because, 
1. I pushed rdi(8bytes) before malloc -> 2. call malloc -> 3. return address(8byte) pushed into stack -> 4. Finally 16 bytes aligned !

Could you please help me to understand why my code it works?

Comment: Please check the calling convention of your platform.  Arguments are passed in registers, not on the stack on x86_64 macos.  Note further that as `_my_strlen` likely destroys the value of `rdi`, `push rdi` will not save the value you intended.  The stack alignment is only needed if any function uses SSE instructions with stack references as those require a 16 byte alignment.  If you don't have any of these in your custom functions, no error will occur but your code still does not comply with the ABI requirements.

Comment: @fuz I didn't get your point. First of all, I used `rdi` for receiving value of my_strdup argument and for passing value to malloc. Second, my_strlen, my_strcpy doesn't need stack references, but also malloc neither, no? malloc will take only one argument which is passed by register `rdi`. I wonder why malloc function show me 16 bytes alignment error when i didn't push 8byte `rdi`. My functions and malloc are in same condition (take arguments by register)

Comment: It is the called function that takes care of alignment, so simply CALL can't cause a mishap.  The malloc() call would only fail if it uses SSEx code, that's pretty unlikely.  There is very little point in getting this wrong intentionally.

Comment: The ABI requires RSP to be 16-byte aligned *before* a `call`.  On entry to a function (including yours), it's 8 bytes away from 16-byte alignment so you need an odd number of pushes or something equivalent before another `call`.

Comment: Just because the ABI requires the stack to be aligned doesn’t mean your program will always fail if you do it wrong. (Just like undefined behavior in C, for example.)